# OpenThread Border Router Joiner Security Issue

Tags: openthread

I am currently following the steps to set up a Raspberry Pi 3B as a border router on openthread.io ([here](https://openthread.io/guides/border_router/raspberry_pi_3b)). NCP and joiner are both KW41Z with corresponding switches set when built. When I try to add the joiner using the "joiner start J01NU5", it returns with "Join Failed [Security]".

I set the passphrase to "J01NU5" in the GUI to match the steps. Is there something else that needs to be set on the joiner (panid, PSK, key, etc.) before starting the joiner process?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is probably some issue with KW41Z port. I've raised the issue on OpenThread GitHub and also on NXP support. They may look into it. See the following link for more information: https://github.com/openthread/borderrouter/issues/126

Answer (score 1):

You must first bring up the joiner network interface with

```
> ifconfig up
```

Nothing else is necessary on the joiner before typing

```
> joiner start J01NU5
```

You must, however, have a commissioner that has 'started'. For example, with a CLI commissioner device, before attempting to join you should type:

```
> commissioner start
> commissioner add joiner * J01NU5
```

I would test this first, without using the Thread app + border router. It is possible that the border router is already the commissioner. In this case, the above commands might fail silently. You can power down your border router and then restart your CLI commissioner device, just to be sure.

Once you know that your joiner is capable of joining a new network (perhaps JOINER=1 was not specified when you compiled your joiner--check this), you can try with your border router as commissioner:

If you are using your border router and the Thread app, you should first get the eui64 on your joiner device, because the Thread app will ask you for it.

There are a number of things that can screw up the process:

Your joiner does not have encryption capability (this is possible with the NXP devices, if you compiled the stock openthread source). You can always attempt to join your network (if you know the network data) without using encryption by typing:

```
> channel ##
> panid 0x####
> masterkey ################
> ifconfig up
> thread start
```

Another possible problem: perhaps you configured your border router manually (without using the http://localhost interface), and you did not restart otbr-agent and otbr-www.

I would first try joining by specifying masterkey, panid, channel (directly above). Then try powering device off, waiting for it to be forgotten by the network, and then by using a CLI commissioner. And lastly by using the border router and the Thread app (after powering off, and waiting a while).

Good luck,

David

Comment: command is updated to 'sudo wpanctl commissioner joiner-add  '*' 60 J01NU5', where 60 is how much time you have to join in seconds